# Xamarin iOS Read Console after Device was locked

Tags: ios, sockets, xamarin, device, locked

I am programming a iOS App which uses Sockets to communicate with a Server and if the connection was interrupted, it automatically reconnects. But I found an issue losing while running on a Device which gets locked and unlocked. Normally I would output some values to the console or better, debug the whole Application. The problem is that locking the Device stops the Xamarin debugger and the App will freeze.

Is there a tool to reattach or get the complete console output?

## EDIT

here is the [crash report](https://owncloud.dirtyandnative.de/index.php/s/9XKIery9ZVBam7U) from Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XCode -> Windows -> Devices, connect your device via USB and select it, and then you should be able to view the device logs

Comment: Well I tried to find out the line where it crashed but could not find it. I added the crash report inside the post, maybe you can help me finding it